# Как на сайте сделать такую зелёную же полоску, как на скриншоте

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Как на сайте сделать такую зелёную полоску

[image: Тот самый скриншот]

Comment: Изображение должно быть в теле поста, а не ссылкой, пожалуйста, воспользуйтесь кнопкой "Правит", чтобы добавить изображение.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3):

Пропишите внутри тега `<head></head>` этот метатег:
`<meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">`
Примените ваш цвет. Должно получиться примерно так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="lt">

<head>
    <!--другие теги-->
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#005c74" />
    <!--другие теги-->
</head>
<body>
<!--тело проекта-->
</body>
```

`введите сюда код`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Духсообщества всё вполне понятно